# How to draw svg graphics with painter class

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I'm trying to learn how to use the drawing functions. Till now i have been able to use the QPainter class to draw some circles on a QWidget like this:

in MainWindow.h i added:

```
 virtual void paintEvents(QPaintEvent *event);
```

Then in MainWindow.cpp i added:

```
void MainWindow::paintEvents(QPaintEvent *event) {
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawEllipse( 305, 55, 475, 475 );
    painter.drawEllipse( 320, 70, 445, 445 );
    painter.end();
}
```

This draws me some circles in pixels, but i need svg. So how can i use the QPainter class to draw svg circles instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Qt SVG module](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsvg-index.html). If you are using qmake, add `QT += svg` to your `.pro` file and then you will be able to use SVG classes.
Then, you can utilize [QSvgRenderer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsvgrenderer.html) to draw svg documents with your QPainter instance like:

```
#include <QSvgRenderer>
...
void MainWindow::paintEvents(QPaintEvent *event) {
    QPainter painter(this);
    QSvgRenderer svgr("/path/to/img.svg");
    svgr.render(&painter);
    painter.end();
}
```

As per documentation `render` method has two other overloads which will give you control over where and what to render.
You may also want to load your svg content from QByteArray or XML stream which have their appropriate constructors or load methods.

Comment: Trying to understand this. What you do is loading a svg file? But i want to draw? How would QSvgRenderer help me with this?

Comment: I want to create svg image based on coordinates using some lineEdits. Have been thinking about taking this route. But think i could rewrite the file every time the lineEdits are changed and then update image afterwards....

Comment: @ArjanPoortman, read the doc carefully. You can load the doc by a QByteArray which could be created by  calling ```toUtf8()``` on a QString. The QString can be a simple svg doc. You can also draw a single element of an svg doc.

Comment: QSvgRenderer svgr(QByteArray(svg.toUtf8())); <- shows nothing? Somethings missing here?